# Div не растягивается по высоте контента

Tags: css, html

Добрый день! Не могу растянуть див по высоте контента внутри него. Вот html и css

HTML

```css
body {
 text-align: left;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #777777; height: 100%;
 background-color: #ededeb;
 }

.mainbody{
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
}

.content{
margin: auto;
display: block;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  max-width: 1480px;
  padding-left: 113px;

}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="mainbody"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainbody" style="xmhtl" />
<div class="content"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="crimea" style="xmhtl" /></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: для этого `body` укажите `height:100%;` и только после этого элементу `height:100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Добавь `min-height` и `overflow`:

```
.content{
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1480px;
  padding-left: 113px;
  //*****
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```